# Django-celery + redis not show tasks

Tags: django, redis, celery, django-celery

I'm use django-celery and redis with this config:

```
BROKER_URL = "redis://192.168.1.79:6379/0"
BROKER_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_SEND_EVENTS=True
CELERYBEAT_SCHEDULER="djcelery.schedulers.DatabaseScheduler"
CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"
CELERY_REDIS_HOST = "192.168.1.79"
CELERY_REDIS_PORT = 6379
CELERY_REDIS_DB = 0
```

In django-admin I'm not see tasks.
What errors in config?

Answer (score 0):

Might be because you configured `CELERY_RESULT_BACKEND = "redis"`. As far as I know, this means you use redis to store your results.

To use django admin to view your tasks I believe you'd need to store them on the same database that django is using.

Answer (score 0):

Try running manage.py celerycam.

It takes snapshots of celery to update the django-admin.